Can I remove grates/grills from windowed door?
My walkout basement had a windowed door. It has the decorative grills/grates consisting of 9 squares.
I loosened the screws holding the grills and the glass seemed to move. Can I remove these to clean the glass without an issue or concern of breakage?

Some pics would help you here.

The glass should have a secondary/primary means of being mounted to the door.    i would not count on it till proven, so having a second person there to hold the glass will not hurt.  The grills should be just decorative, and not there to hold the glass.  The glass moving might mean the caulking is loose, and needs replacing.

is the wood grid on both sides

It very much depends on the specific construction of the 9-light door.
If the grids are a single piece of molded plastic that also includes the trim around the windowpane that holds it in place, then it will require removing the windowpane, with attendant risk of breakage, to remove the grid from the windowpane. The inner and outter grids and frames hold the glass unit between them - the screws hold the two grids together, which holds them (and the glass) in the door. When re-installing, pay attention to the seals so it doesn't leak. Generally, hardly worth it for window-cleaning.

Image source no affiliation or endorsement. Click image to enlarge.
Other styles of construction permit removing the grid without removing the frame. The "somewhat rare these days" construction with 9 individual pieces of glass that the "grid on a larger pane" is trying to copy the look of cannot be removed, though the individual glass panes can be removed from it. But you would only do that to replace a broken one, normally, not for mere cleaning.

In this case I removed the screws from the window frame. The interior popped off, the exterior was being pushed in by my wife. Opened the door and it came out with the glass (glued?) to the frame.
I cleaned on a flatbed. Added the film and stuck it back in without issues. https://imgur.com/a/a7IbiGS
Thanks all!
